# Stop Meteor from running in Babun

Tags: shell, meteor

I just installed Babun and have added a path in the .zshrc file. But now that I've started Meteor in my application, I don't know how to stop it. I've tried Ctrl C but it doesn't work. How do I stop Meteor from running?